# What is best practice for coding urls in an angular4 app used in multiple environments?

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have an angular 4 app and I am trying to find a best practices approach to creating a solution for creating a service or some sort of a solution for handling many urls for making http requests in a development as well as a production environment.

My solution at this point looks like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
/**
 * PathsService is like a properties file for all of the URL paths used in the application.
 */
@Injectable()
export class PathsService {

  constructor() {}

  productionEnvironment:string = "https://myproductionenvironment.com"
  developmentEnvironment:string = "https://mydevelopmentenvironment.com"

  activeRoot:string = productionEnvironment;


  loginResource = "/loginresources"
  employeeResource = "/employeeresouces"

  public getLoginResources(): string {
    return this.activeRoot+this.loginResource;
  }

  public getEmployeeResource():string {
    return this.activeRoot+this.employeeResource;
  }




}
```

While I believe this would work fine, there is a small problem because I have to change the activeRoot when switching from development to production environments. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, so I don't have to manually switch. I could use javascript to take the url, parse it, and switch between production and development environments in that way, but it seems like there should be a better more angular way to solve this issue. Any input on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you can take a look @ this link http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the Angular CLI, you have a folder called `environments`. In this, you have `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`.

In both files you have an exported object. In this object, you can add a `let apiUrl = 'your URL;`. Then, in your files, you **import only the first one** (`environment.ts`)

Then, when you build, you just have to run `ng build --prod`, and when compiling, instead of using `environment.ts`, it will use `environment.prod.ts`

Is that clear enough ?

Comment: yeah! Just a complement, you can create any environments files you wanted (environment dev, staging etc) and with your integration continuous tool (or not) build with the environment file wanted.

Comment: Exactly, when building, just use `ng build --environment=anyEnv`

Answer (score 2):

use angular cli and you'll get environment.dev.ts and environment.prod.ts built at compile time.

for example:
http://www.alternatestack.com/development/app-development/angular2-environment-specific-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Angular CLI you should have two files, `src/environments/environment.ts` and `src/environments/environment.prod.ts`. In this files you can assign environment variables for your production and development purposes. Just `import { environment } from '../environments/environment'` and you'll be all set. The CLI will automatically select the right environment for you.